# how do I get sbt to gather all the jar files my code depends on into one place?

Tags: scala, jar, sbt

I'm new to [sbt](/questions/tagged/sbt). I want it to put all the dependency `jar` files as well as my jar file into one place. SBT will run the app, but I've got various dependencies scattered around and an `.ivy` folder full of things my jar file depends on indirectly.

So Is there a simple command to copy them all into a single place so I can distribute it to another machine?

Comment: Yes, this is real pain. Maybe I missed something but I really don't understand why this is not a part of _Simple_ Build Tool

Comment: @AlexPovar: I guess there are so many ways of doing this that picking one and standardizing it could be detrimental (but convenient I agree).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are many plugins you can use: [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/eed3si9n/sbt-assembly), [sbt-proguard](https://github.com/nuttycom/sbt-proguard-plugin), [sbt-onejar](https://github.com/retronym/sbt-onejar), [xitrum-package](https://github.com/xitrum-framework/xitrum-package) etc.

See the [list of SBT plugins](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Community-Plugins.html).

Comment: What are the differences?

Answer (score 14):

Add the following line to your `build.sbt` file.

```
retrieveManaged := true
```

This will gather the dependencies locally

Comment: Thanks for the hint. How did you know about this - is there a link to sbt 0.13.13 documentation (I didn't find). It works - `sbt compile` gathers dependencies under `lib_unmanaged/`.

Comment: Mentioned in http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Faq.html#Where+has+0.7%E2%80%99s++gone%3F

Comment: Thanks a lot, I like this approach, don't wanna config for difference plugin. However, it look like retrieveManaged won't get the depend for java library which managed by maven, if there solution about that?

Comment: Doesn't work for sbt 1.30
https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/5078
Downgrade your sbt if you really want to use this feature

Answer (score 11):

**Create a task in your build file like this:**

```
lazy val copyDependencies = TaskKey[Unit]("pack")

def copyDepTask = copyDependencies <<= (update, crossTarget, scalaVersion) map {
  (updateReport, out, scalaVer) =>
    updateReport.allFiles foreach {
      srcPath =>
        val destPath = out / "lib" / srcPath.getName
        IO.copyFile(srcPath, destPath, preserveLastModified = true)
    }
}
```

**Add the Task to a Project like this:**

```
lazy val HubSensors =
  Project("HubSensors", file("HubSensors"), settings = shared ++ Seq(
    copyDepTask,
    resolvers ++= Seq(novusRels),
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      jodatime
    )
  )) dependsOn(HubCameraVision, JamServiceProxy, HubDAL)
```

**In the SBT console type:**

```
project [Project Name]
pack
```

Comment: I see two difficulties in this approach, in particular with large projects:
1. Running _update_ on multiple projects with interdependencies ends up copying the same .jar more than once;
2. You may have the same dependency but with distinct versions being copied. This happens in general with popular libraries, like log4j and apache-commons, because the same artifact is transitively referenced by multiple dependencies.
See task ``evicted`` for more information.
You can do something like (pseudo code) "allFiles - evicted", but it's far from trivial. You will have to dive deep into the SBT API.

Comment: But, for small projects, your approach would be perfectly fine.

Answer (score 8):

Try sbt-pack plugin https://github.com/xerial/sbt-pack, which collects all dependent jars in target/pack folder and also generates launch scripts.

Comment: I've just moved from sbt-onejar to sbt-pack and I have to say it's very nice: fast, easy to use and reliable.

Answer (score 4):

You could also try SBT Native Packager: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager (sbt 0.7+)

This is still a WIP but will be used in Play Framework 2.2 in the coming weeks.
With this, you can create standalone ZIP files, Debian packages (DEB), Windows installation packages (MSI), DMG, RPM, and so on.

Comment: To help a little further, with sbt-native-packager installed, one would do `sbt stage` to get the files in `target/universal/stage`

Answer (score 2):

The SBT docs have a [list of "One Jar Plugins"](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Community/Community-Plugins.html#one-jar-plugins):

> - sbt-assembly: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly
> - xsbt-proguard-plugin: https://github.com/adamw/xsbt-proguard-plugin
> - sbt-deploy: https://github.com/reaktor/sbt-deploy
> - sbt-appbundle (os x standalone): https://github.com/sbt/sbt-appbundle
> - sbt-onejar (Packages your project using One-JAR™): https://github.com/sbt/sbt-onejar

Answer (score 0):

May you looking for this sbt plugin: https://github.com/anvie/sbt-onedir-plugin