# Include Dependencies in JAR using SBT package

Tags: scala, sbt

Apparently project dependencies are not being packaged into the jar generated by:

```
sbt package
```

How can dependencies be included?

Comment: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly

Comment: http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/

Comment: @dmitry Has problems with Spark.  Stackoverflow is loaded with similar interop problems.

Comment: @Aaron +1 for learning something new.  docs and activity look good. attempting this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38335207/spark-core-1-6-1-play-json-2-4-8-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-play-api-libs/38351257

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979336/how-do-i-get-sbt-to-gather-all-the-jar-files-my-code-depends-on-into-one-place

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a project called onejar that will package a project and all its dependencies into a single jar file. There is an SBT plugin as well:

https://github.com/sbt/sbt-onejar

However if you're just looking to create a standard package (deb, rpm, etc.) there is sbt-native-packager:

https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager

It can place all your dependencies into a Linux package and add the appropriate wrappers to load all your dependencies and start your program or service.

Answer (score 21):

Well, I use [`sbt-assembly` plugin](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#using-published-plugin) to create jar with dependencies,

**(1) add `sbt-assembly` to `projects/assembly.sbt`**

```
echo 'addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.8")' > project/assembly.sbt
```

**(2)** **run `sbt clean assembly` to build the jar**. 
It will create `${name}-assembly-${version}.jar` in `target/scala-${scalaVersion}`

*(3) Only in case you get infamous de-duplicate error, use `assemblyMergeStrategy` as described [in here](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#merge-strategy)*

Comment: Note that sbt-assembly is not available for scala 2.11 (and never will be)

Comment: @HansHarhoff "never" is a word mostly used by storytellers.. >> 
https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly/issues/115, 
https://index.scala-lang.org/sbt/sbt-assembly/sbt-assembly/0.14.5?target=_2.12_1.0  
do not make us waste time.

Comment: if you get the infamous de-duplicate errors you're screwed, because as of December 2020, they are impossible to fix even with mergeStrategy.